# flutter TextField sticky, cursor jumps back to it when I finish with other items

Tags: flutter, focus, textfield

On my new Job screen I have an About TextFormField widget, if I put some text into this, then go onto to interact with other Widgets, such as getting the time the job starts, once I've finished with those widgets, the cursor jump back to the TextFormField, Flutter assumes the user has unfinished business.

How do I tell Flutter not to reactivate TestField widgets?  To keep the cursor invisible, and focus elsewhere?

I've tried googling for the answer, doubtless, it's there, I just don't have the vocabulary, but it led me to think it has something to do with focus.  I tried setting autofocus: false, but that wasn't it.

```
      Column(children: <Widget>[
       TextFormField(
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
          //errorText: _showValidationError ? 'Invalid number entered' : null,
          labelText: 'Comprehensive job description',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          ),
        ),
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        onSaved: (String description) =>
            this.widget.job.description = description.trim(),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _selectDate(context, startDate),
        child: Text('Select start date'),
      ),
      // TODO only show for certain categories
      CheckboxListTile(
        secondary: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        title: Text('To be completed the same day?'),
        subtitle: Text(showEndDatePicker == true
            ? "Must be completed same day."
            : "Could be completed in a few days."),
        value: showEndDatePicker ?? false,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            showEndDatePicker = value;
          });
        },
      ),
  Visibility(
    visible: !showEndDatePicker ?? false,
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => _selectDate(context, endDate),
      child: Text('Select end date'),
    ),
  ),
   ]
);
```

If I type some stuff in the TextFormField, then click the raised button it summons a Date picker.  Perfect.  But when that is completed, the focus jumps back to the TextFormField, popping up the keyboard.  The user has likely finished with this field.

Having the cursor jump back a few Widgets and the keyboard popup inexplicably is bad UX, help!

Comment: It is better to provide the full code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it with UnfocusDisposition. Try following this example: [unfocus method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/unfocus.html).